# How to find current QtWebKit version used in Qt SDK?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I want to know the version of QtWebKit module being used in Qt SDK.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.QTWEBKIT_VERSION_STR Macro gives QtWebKit Version.

2.qWebKitVersion() gives webkit version used.

Comment: any way to inspect this from the terminal?