# How can add an user agent to my browser?

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developping a blackberry 10 mobile application using the momentics IDE (BB native SDK).

I want to add an user agent to my web browser like below which is described in this link : [**blackberry-10-user-agent-string**](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/08/blackberry-10-user-agent-string/)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; <Device Model>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Version> (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/<BB Version #> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Version>
```

What I want is, how can I detect the **device model, webkit version** and the **BB version** using code (C++) to put them in the using agent string?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the header value to the request object by calling [QNetworkRequest::setHeader()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#setHeader) with `QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader` as the header type and the actual string as as the value.

**EDIT:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421747/how-to-find-current-qtwebkit-version-used-in-qt-sdk) shows hot to get the WebKit version from Qt.

[This](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html) class should provide all the information about the device.

[This](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__platforminfo.html) class should provide the actual os version.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! but this is not what I meant. I know how to add a header but I don't know how to detect the device model, webkit version and the BB version to add them to the string of the user agent

Comment: Ahh, sorry misunderstood the question. Edited the answer at least for the WebKit part, not sure about the blackberry information, you should look in their sdk.

Comment: Ok, googled all the info about how to retrieve the information needed for constructing the header, hope it solves everything.